# DataTemplate without Keys in ResourceDictionary in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have several DataTemplates in a `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:z="clr-namespace:ZoomPan">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type z:Circle}">
        <z:Circle Center="{Binding Center}" Radius="{Binding Radius}" x:Name="circle"/>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger ... />
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    .... etc.
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I use it in a `Window`:

```
<z:MyUserControl>
    <z:MyUserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </z:MyUserControl.Resources>
</z:MyUserControl>
```

And the DataTemplates and triggers work ok.

I have two questions:

- Why do DataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary not need a x:Key?
- Can I divide the ResourceDictionary somehow in sections with a Key and then point to the DataTemplates in a section?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why do DataTemplates in a ResourceDictionary not need a x:Key?

When you're missing a key for `Style` or `DataTemplate`, this construction:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
```

automatically converted to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Type local:MyType}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyType}">
```

This means that the Style/DataTemplate will be used explicitly for all controls of this type because in `ResourceDictionaries` can not be elements without keys, rather this is done to simplify the structure. Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx):

> Setting the TargetType property to the TextBlock type without setting an x:Key `implicitly sets the x:Key to {x:Type TextBlock}.` This also means that if you give the above Style an x:Key value of anything other than {x:Type TextBlock}, the Style would not be applied to all TextBlock elements automatically. Instead, you need to apply the style to the TextBlock elements explicitly.

---

> When I give the DataTemplates a Key they stop to work

When you specify a key for `DataTemplate`, it should be used for this key, such as:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MainView}"> // here set the key

    <MainWindowViewModels:MainViewModel />
</ContentControl>
```

---

> Can I divide the ResourceDictionary somehow in sections with a Key and then point to the DataTemplates in a section?

Unfortunately no, ResourceDictionary is [`Quote`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> class is not derived from `DictionaryBase`. Instead, the ResourceDictionary class implements `IDictionary`  but relies on a Hashtable internally.

In this case, it is not ordered dictionary in which each element is assigned to the hash. For the separation of dictionaries regions used [`ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there a chance to bind a set of DataTemplates with 'StaticResource' ? For example multiple HierarchicalDataTemplates of a TreeView. I want to separate the large Templates from the Window structure and keep them in the Resources somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, you can put an x:Key on them, but the x:Type allows them to affect all of that type in the children of the control they are a resource for. It also sets an *implicit* x:Key on the item. The remarks in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation explain this very well.

To answer the second, it would be very difficult. You could define each in a separate resource dictionary and use clever merging. As far as an easy way, I believe the answer is no.

Comment: When I give the DataTemplates a Key they stop to work. The msdn explains it indeed, but not for ResourceDictionary though where I was looking.

Comment: Right, the documentation is for the DataType property of the DataTemplate class, not where I would start either (though I got there by googling "DataTemplate x:key".